# Can a singly linked list have an array in its head? (in C)

Tags: c, data-structures, singly-linked-list

I am a beginner C programmer. I am currently learning about linked lists. Most examples explain about storing/ inserting one data element in each head of a link list like this:

**[1],[address of next node] -> [2],[address of next node] -> [3],[address of next node] ->......**

However, I would like to know if it is possible to store multiple elements in linked list as follows:

**[1,2,3],[address of next node] -> [4,5,6],[address of next node] -> [7,8,9],[Address of next node] -> .....**

[ ],[ ] represent a node with data and link.
Data in the above representation has 3 elements stored in the form of array.

PS: Sorry for a bad visual representation.

TIA

Comment: yes, the examples show only one kind of data (typically integers), but in practice you can make your lists store anything you want

Comment: The data in a linked list node, its "payload", can be anything, as long as it's of the same type in all nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have multiple data in each node of the linked list. One example is-

```
typedef struct node{
    int val;
    int val2;
    int array[30];
    char x;
    struct node *next;
}node;
```

And you can access the array like this-

```
n.array[index] // by node variable(n is a variable name)
n->array[index] // by node pointer(n is a node pointer)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can store anything in your linked list. To store different types of variables, you need to use struct. And for each node you need to allocate enough memory for it. Lets give an example, you want to store an array int[10] in a struct. Then this will be your node:

```
struct node
{
    int array[10]
    struct node * next;
};
```

To allocate enough space:

```
struct Node* node = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
```

Then you can access nodes array by:

```
node.array[0] = 10;
node.array[1] = 11;
```

so on